# Edit view link redirected to preview link automatically

Tags: views

I have opened **edit view** option on localhost using Drupal 7. firstly, the requested page i.e **http://localhost/xxx/drupal/admin/structure/views/view/products/edit/block_14?destination=node** open successfully, however, It automatically redirected to edit preview link i.e **http://localhost/xxx/drupal/admin/structure/views/view/products/preview/block_14**. I have tried to find the problem but not able to do.

kindly assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem, it's done on purpose for convenience of being able to quickly edit the view and return to the page where you were at initially.

If you want to stay at edit page then just remove the `?destination=node` part from the URL: `http://localhost/xxx/drupal/admin/structure/views/view/products/edit/block_14`

Comment: thank you for your answer, however, it did not work for me.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work - the destination either set or not and there is simply no other way. Give me an access and I'll fix the problem for you.

Comment: there were some issues regarding Ajax, which created some conflicts, now it's working fine. Thank you:)

Comment: Sakura, the answer is correct regardless was caused the issue and should be accepted. You could also provide the detailed description of what actually was causing the problem and the way how you resolved it and accept your own answer, so this page could be useful for other users looking solution for similar problem. Whatever you do, please just do not leave your questions with no answer accepted if you want them to keep helping you.